# Finding c2s connection on ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to find out client to server connection(C2S) and c2s_tls connection on ejabberd.Is there any inbuilt command or function in ejabberd regarding this?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. Could you please clarify a bit are you looking at the place where this is implemented ? ejabberd_c2s.erl module is a good start.

Comment: There is a module statsdx.erl in ejabberd.This module provides us with statistics of ejabbered(Like total no of online users,total number of registerd users,total no of client to server(c2s) connection,total no of client to server connection on tls etc)on ejabberd GUI.But on my ejabberd c2s tls and c2s connection is always zero(When i read the file statsdx i found this functionality (c2s tls connection and c2s) was basically not implemented).Now i am trying to write code in that statsdx file which will fetch and show c2s_tls and c2s connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be found in session table